# How to do translations in Wordpress?

Tags: translation

I want my website to be in English and French, but I'm not sure how to make this happen. I have an excel spreadsheet with French translations for each English page in the site.

How to translations work? I would prefer to code it myself instead of using a plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/222380/109616

Comment: also here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/117612/109616

Comment: Are you trying to translate a theme or the content of your website?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) plugin to create a translation.
If you are creating a theme, you should specify the `Text Domain` and `Domain Path` in your `style.css` file.

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme Name
Author: My Name
Author URI: http://sample.url
Description: Your theme description
Version: 1.0.0
Text Domain: mydomain
Domain Path: /lang
*/
```

Next, add some text in your theme.

```
<?php echo __( 'Hello there', 'mydomain' ); ?>
```

Then go to your wp-admin and you should find `Hello there text` and translate it to any languages you wish.